# How to use relational queries in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I have 3 classes.

1) Country 
  (Country contains country_name and country_id)

2) City 
 (City contains city_name and city_id)

3) Place 
 (Place contains place_name, city_id and country_id)

When i query to fetch details of a Place, can I get city_name,country_name based on city_id and country_id in the Place details without using multiple queries.

Comment: you should store City pointer and Country pointer in City table and when querying on Place table just include this pointer in your query. You get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If these three tables are joined you can do but If you said I don't want to that this needs multiple queries. You could merge all entities in a table not three tables. But it makes data repeat of data. I hope it'll help. Good luck

Comment: Place class contains many other fields, to avoid data clutter, I have to use separate classes.